# Check Span Element with ID for text in Selenium/Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I want to refresh a page until a certain text changes. However, both texts are permanently present several times on the page.

So I need to check a span element with an ID and a specific text at the same time.

Can someone tell me how to do this with `driver.find_element(By.XPATH,)`?

Thanks and greetings
Jannis

```py
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//span[text()="Derzeit nicht verfügbar"]')
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Provide the relevant HTML of the desired tag as text in your question.

Answer (score 1):

`//span[@id='example' and text()='Hello World!']` should work for you here.

Answer (score 0):

You need an AND operator in your XPATH.

This is the syntax:

```
//tag_name[@name = 'Name value' and @id = ‘ID value’]
```

So you can construct your XPATH something like below:

```
//span[text()="Derzeit nicht verfügbar" and @id="enter id value here"]
```